# How to use UISearchBar and SearchDisplayController without UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I have a custom `UIScrollView` , some `UIView` like `collectionView`. I wanna use `UISearchBar` and `SearchDisplayController` to search and display the content like the application screen on Mac OS below:

[image]

Anyone know this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, Leave the `UISearchBarController`. Use `UITextField` or `UISearchBar` and implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method if you use `UITextField` for Search.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

return YES;
}
```

When you get the object in the Filtered Array. Use any GirdView for showing your result. You can also use `UICollectionView` too. or some third party Libs, Like `CHGridView`.